# How to detect In-App Purchase's Status on Activity Result Method

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am testing In-App Purchase using Static References.
I am using the Static Reference `android.test.purchased` but i can't figure out how to get the response of the Test Purchase in my `onActivityResult(...)` Method.

Here is my `onActivityResult(....)` Method's Body:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("In-App", "Data = "+data.toString());
    Log.d("In-App", "Request Code = "+requestCode);
    Log.d("In-App", "Result Code = "+resultCode);
}
```

My Logcat says:

```
08-16 10:48:10.114: D/In-App(3889): Data = Intent { (has extras) }
08-16 10:48:10.114: D/In-App(3889): Request Code = 666
08-16 10:48:10.114: D/In-App(3889): Result Code = -1
```

Screen Shots of my Test Purchase:
1.

[image]

2.

[image]

The question is that, what extras should i extract from the `Data Object` in my `onActivityResult(....)` method, to detect the status of the current test purchase (Canceled, already purchased, Successfully accepted, etc) and the information about the product (`JSON respnse`)?
Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have updated my `onActivityResult(...)` Method

```
  int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
  String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
  String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     //Purchased Status = Purchased
     try {
        //Product Details JSON
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);

        //Purchased Product ID
        String sku = jo.getString("productId");
      }
      catch (JSONException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  else {
     //Purchased Status = Not Purchased
     }
```

This way i have got the purchase's status and the purchased product's details `JSON`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need a database to persist the orders. Second of all, when the user install the your app. You have to issue a `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS` what the user has bought and insert the result into the local database. you can read more [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html).

**EDITED:**

For more details check out [In-App Billing Integration](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/)

Comment: I agree to your `Data persistence` and `Restore Transactions` advice. But you have not answered my question.

Comment: Are you using In-app Billing V3?